# Condition to check valid account number

Tags: joptionpane

I am asking user (using `JOptionPane`) to input account number. I would like to ask how could I check that if inputs is all integers, then the program will continue otherwise it will show an error message and would ask the user to input again until valid input. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possible a duplicated question : See here: 
[Check if input is an integer in JOptionPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598253/check-if-input-is-an-integer-in-joptionpane)

But if it was a web form, You could simply attach an onKeyUp event handler and parse the value every time the user types something in that field.

by JavaScript, you can use .isNaN() to determine if the value is a legal numeric value. Or JQuery's .isNumeric() can do this as well.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Validate to restrict character on input filed ..

```js
 $Validate = $("#form1").validate({
            rules: {
                accountnumber: {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                CampaignName: {
                    required: "*"
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form name='form1' id='form1' method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='accountnumber' id='txtAccountNumber' />
  </form>
```